# Struts2 map iteration in JSP from session

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hashmap, struts-tags

In JSP:

```xml
<s:if test="%{#session.cart==null}">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Your cart is empty.
</s:if>
<s:else>    
<s:set var="cartlist" value="%{#session.cart}"/>

<s:iterator value="#cartlist">
<s:iterator value="value" status="cart">

<s:property value="#cart.pid"/>

</s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
</s:else>
```

Why this `else` part is not iterating. What I'm doing wrong. If cart is empty, `if` condition is evaluated correctly. If cart is not empty then `else` part is evaluated but the loop is not iterating means it does not displays any thing.

In Action:

```
Map<Integer,Cart> map = new HashMap<Integer,Cart>();
map.put(map.size()+1,new Cart(pid,delivery,price,qty));
session.setAttribute("cart",map);
```

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<s:if test="%{#session.cart==null}">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Your cart is empty.
</s:if>
<s:else>    
<s:set var="cartlist" value="%{#session.cart}"/>
    <!-- following iterator returns Map.Entry of the map-->
    <s:iterator value="%{#carList}">
        <!-- This iterator loops through all the entries of the map -->
        <s:iterator>
            <s:property value="key"/>
            <s:property value="value.pid"/>
        </s:iterator>
    </iterator>
</s:else>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it. This is enough:

```xml
<s:if test="%{#session.cart==null}">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;Your cart is empty.
</s:if>
<s:else>    
    <s:iterator value="%{#session.cart}">
        <s:property value="key"/>
        <s:property value="value.pid"/>
    </iterator>
</s:else>
```